# Sanitizing user inputs that are part of dynamic PL/SQL command

Tags: plsql, user-input, dynamic-sql, sanitization, in-operator

I have a table filled by users and its VARCHAR2 records contain a part of executable PL/SQL code "IN(user_input)". I wonder how I can sanitize these user inputs or maybe revrite it to be more efficient. All my ideas failed so far. For example:

- A Bind variable is not accepted in this case
- DBMS_ASSERT.enquote_literal always raise an exception etc.

Thank you very much for any help.

```
/* A "MY_PARAMETER" column is part of SQL: ...WHERE MY_DATA IN(MY_PARAMETER)... */
CREATE TABLE my_parameter_table (
       "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ENABLE,
       "MY_PARAMETER" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ENABLE   
)

INSERT INTO my_parameter_table ("ID","MY_PARAMETER") VALUES (1,'6,7,8');
INSERT INTO my_parameter_table ("ID","MY_PARAMETER") VALUES (2,'''b'',''g'',''k''');
INSERT INTO my_parameter_table ("ID","MY_PARAMETER") VALUES (3,'SELECT dummy FROM dual'); -- return "X"

/* Tested table with data */
CREATE TABLE my_data_table (
       "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL ENABLE,
       "MY_DATA" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ENABLE,
       "MY_RESULT" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ENABLE   
);

INSERT INTO my_data_table ("ID","MY_DATA","MY_RESULT") VALUES (1,'a','NOT');
INSERT INTO my_data_table ("ID","MY_DATA","MY_RESULT") VALUES (2,'b','THIS'); --WILL PASS
INSERT INTO my_data_table ("ID","MY_DATA","MY_RESULT") VALUES (3,'c','NOT');
INSERT INTO my_data_table ("ID","MY_DATA","MY_RESULT") VALUES (4,'X','IS'); --WILL PASS
INSERT INTO my_data_table ("ID","MY_DATA","MY_RESULT") VALUES (5,'Y','NOT');
INSERT INTO my_data_table ("ID","MY_DATA","MY_RESULT") VALUES (6,'Z','CORRECT'); --WILL PASS

/* Result table where results are inserted */
CREATE TABLE my_result_table (
       "MESSAGE" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ENABLE   
);

/* ------------------------------------------- */

DECLARE
    where_condition VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
    v_query VARCHAR2(1000) := '';
    insert_or VARCHAR2(5) := '';

    CURSOR test_parameter_cur IS
        (
          SELECT * FROM my_parameter_table            
        );
    test_parameter_rec test_parameter_cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

    /* Read all parameters and build an WHERE condition */
    OPEN test_parameter_cur;
    LOOP 
        FETCH test_parameter_cur INTO test_parameter_rec; 
        EXIT WHEN test_parameter_cur%NOTFOUND;

        /* Condition check can be any type. Varchar, number, date or some subselect */
        IF test_parameter_rec.ID = 1 THEN where_condition := where_condition || insert_or || 'd.ID IN('|| test_parameter_rec.MY_PARAMETER ||')';
        ELSE where_condition := where_condition || insert_or || 'd.MY_DATA IN('|| test_parameter_rec.MY_PARAMETER ||')';
        END IF;
        insert_or := ' OR '; -- after first run the "OR" operator is inserted in front of each where condition 

    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE test_parameter_cur; 

v_query := 'INSERT INTO my_result_table(MESSAGE) 
           (SELECT d.MY_RESULT FROM my_data_table d
           WHERE '|| where_condition ||')';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;
COMMIT; 
END;

/* Now the my_result_table contains 3 records: THIS, IS, CORRECT */
SELECT * FROM my_result_table;

DROP TABLE my_parameter_table; 
DROP TABLE my_data_table;
```

Comment: Do you want to authorize your user to enter subqueries (like the SELECT FROM DUAL)?

Comment: The script should be able to evaluate various set of parameters using IN operator. The parameters are defined by user. I don't know about any other universal solution, than write IN-parameters directly. It isn't still decided who will fill the parameters (users or admin on request), but it should be sanitised anyway. That means for example that SELECT is allowed, but DROP prohibited.

Comment: There is an example, that is much more simple. I still wonder, if there is any way to make it safe.                                                             user_input := '''a'',''b'',''c''';
/* OR */
user_input := '1,2,3,4';
/* OR */
user_input := 'SELECT code FROM nationality';

/* Some function depended on many things. */
where_condition := 'd.any_data_type_column IN(' || user_input || ')';

v_query := 'INSERT INTO my_result_table(result) 
           (SELECT d.result_column FROM my_data_table d
           WHERE '|| where_condition ||')';        
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;

Comment: If you let your users write SELECT, you trust them to know SQL. I wouldn't sanitize the input (except replace `'` with `''`). Anything else would be pointless really. Remebmer that this function could be easily abused: your users could do almost anything that SQL*Plus could do with the same user.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your advice. Though the users are internal and can be trusted in a way, I'll keep trying to prevent some risks. I decided to check user input by a regular expression. I can share it if it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here : https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement

Works like a charme for ',' - separated list. I recommend to TRIM() the result to remove trailing and leading blanks from the results.

You can use the select-statement as a subselect in an in-clause.